Show payment popup in nextjs
I want to include a payment method in my nextjs project. When I send the request to the server, a script is returned to me. I need to receive payment using a popup using this, but I couldn't find how to show it on the page.
result:
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
   if (typeof iyziInit == 'undefined') {
      var iyziInit = {
         currency:\"TRY\",
         token:\"7531ab23-4f95-44e0-9e93-0f80ae09ad06\",
         price:125.00,
         pwiPrice:125.00,
         locale:\"tr\",
         baseUrl:\"https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com\",          
         merchantGatewayBaseUrl:\"https://sandbox-merchantgw.iyzipay.com\", 
         registerCardEnabled:true,
         bkmEnabled:true,
         bankTransferEnabled:false,
         bankTransferTimeLimit:                  
                  {\"value\":5,\"type\":\"day\"},
         bankTransferRedirectUrl:\"\",
         bankTransferCustomUIProps:{},
         campaignEnabled:false,
         campaignMarketingUiDisplay:null,
         paymentSourceName:\"\",
         plusInstallmentResponseList:null,
         payWithIyzicoSingleTab:false,
         payWithIyzicoSingleTabV2:false,
         payWithIyzicoOneTab:false,
         newDesignEnabled:false,
         mixPaymentEnabled:true,
         creditCardEnabled:true,
         bankTransferAccounts:[],
         userCards:[],
         fundEnabled:true,memberCheckoutOtpData:{},
         force3Ds:false,
         isSandbox:true,
         storeNewCardEnabled:true,
         paymentWithNewCardEnabled:true,
         enabledApmTypes:[\"SOFORT\",\"IDEAL\",\"QIWI\",\"GIROPAY\"],
         payWithIyzicoUsed:false,
         payWithIyzicoEnabled:true,
         payWithIyzicoCustomUI:{},
         buyerName:\"John\",
         buyerSurname:\"Doe\",
         merchantInfo:\"\",
         merchantName:\"Sandbox Merchant Name - 3399813\",
         cancelUrl:\"\",
         buyerProtectionEnabled:false,
         hide3DS:false,
         gsmNumber:\"\",
         email:\"email@email.com\",
         checkConsumerDetail:{},
         subscriptionPaymentEnabled:false,
         disabledCardStorageInfoCheckbox:false,
         ucsEnabled:false,
         fingerprintEnabled:false,
         payWithIyzicoFirstTab:false,
         creditEnabled:false,
         payWithIyzicoLead:false,
         goBackUrl:\"\",
         metadata : {},
         createTag:function(){
                  var iyziJSTag = document.createElement('script');
                  iyziJSTag.setAttribute('src','https://sandbox-  static.iyzipay.com/checkoutform/v2/bundle.js?v=1725560479959');
                  document.head.appendChild(iyziJSTag);}};iyziInit.createTag();
         }
</script>"

i try this:
{data && <div id="script" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.result.checkoutFormContent }} />}

if i do it like this it doesn't work at all
and i try this:
{data && <Script strategy="afterInteractive" id="script" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.result.checkoutFormContent }} />}

When I tried this I got an error saying unexpected token "<"
But if I run the incoming script in codepen, I can see the result I want, that is, there is no error in the incoming response, I just couldn't figure out how to run it.
https://codepen.io/enesseval/pen/ZEdVGpN
